# Stream copy USB webcam on remote Raspberry Pi to FFmpeg on Windows 11 via FFmpeg, mediamtx, ncat, piping, tunneling or any combination thereof?

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, debian, windows-11, raspberry-pi

**Question**

How do I stream copy raw video and audio from a USB webcam on a remote Raspberry Pi 4B running Raspberry Pi OS to FFmpeg (or a file!) on a machine running Windows 11 via FFmpeg, mediamtx, ncat, piping, tunneling or any combination thereof?
Preferably FFmpeg or mediamtx.

**Goal**

Stream copy rawvideo from "/dev/video0" and stream copy or PCM encode audio from "plughw:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0", on a Raspberry Pi, to a remote machine without saving to the Pi's disk or encoding video on the Pi.

**Why not just encode on the Pi?**

There are machines on the network waiting for work so I would rather the Pi's CPU be used for other things. The Pi is connected to an SSD and the webcam via USB; Reading from the USB camera and writing raw files to the SSD takes a significant portion of available USB bandwidth.

**Notes**

Camera is a PS3Eye; YUYV422, 640x480 @ 60Hz / 320x240 @ 187Hz

FFmpeg version 5.1.3-1+rpt4 on Raspberry Pi (apt installed, not built). Latest FFmpeg version on Windows 11.

Latest (as of Nov, 14) mediamtx and latest Nmap/Ncat on Raspberry Pi. Latest mediamtx and Windows binary installed version of Nmap/Ncat on Windows 11.

FFmpeg and Ncat are allowed through the Firewall.

Pixel format seems to be giving me trouble in some commands. RTSP specifically seems to be displeased by it (YUYV422).

**What seems to be close**

**In mediamtx.yml**

```
runOnInit: FFmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -thread_queue_size 1024 -f alsa -i "plughw:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0" -f v4l2 -framerate 187 -video_size 320x240 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:$RTSP_PORT/$RTSP_PATH
```

This command works in FFmpeg when outputting .mkv locally on the Pi. In -f rtsp or mediamtx it gives the following error;

```
2023/11/15 01:28:18 INF [RTSP] [conn [::1]:33070] opened
[rtsp @ 0x7fe534f318] Unsupported pixel format.
2023/11/15 01:28:18 INF [RTSP] [conn [::1]:33070] closed: EOF
```

**In mediamtx.yml**

```
runOnInit: FFmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -thread_queue_size 1024 -f alsa -i "plughw:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0" -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -framerate 187 -video_size 320x240 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16be -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:$RTSP_PORT/$RTSP_PATH
```

This command works in mediamtx as well as FFmpeg but results in corrupt video as the pixel format passed to ffmpeg for the input camera is wrong.

**Terminal**

```
cat /dev/video0 | ncat 192.1.1.250 9999
```

Does send data (and the right amount for YUYV422, rawvideo, 480p @ 60Hz) to the listening machines ncat (flooding the terminal) but I don't know how to save this data in a usable format. Using -o with or without the append option doesn't result in a usable file.

I feel like I'm really close but missing something simple.

**Update**

I've mostly solved this; I was overthinking things.

The following commands stream copies rawvideo and pcm audio directly from my Raspberry Pi's webcam via FFmpeg and UDP.

For the transmitting FFmpeg client, Raspberry Pi in my case;

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -thread_queue_size 1024 -f alsa -i "plughw:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0" -video_size 640x480 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f matroska udp://ReceiverIP:port
```

For the receiving FFmpeg client, Windows 11 in my case;

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f matroska -i udp://TrasnmitterIP:port -c:v copy -c:a copy Output.mkv
```

This works almost perfectly. I haven't gotten TCP to work yet. Given the nature of UDP I don't really consider this solved.
As a side note to anyone trying something like this later, you can automatically segment you're output video on the receiving side by using the following;

```
-f segment -segment_time 300 -reset_timestamps 1 Output_%03d
```

This splits the output file into 300 second clips and incrementally increases the file names. Change the `-segment_time 300` to whatever suits your needs.

Example;

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f matroska -i udp://TrasnmitterIP:port -c:v copy -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 300 -reset_timestamps 1 Output_%03d.mkv
```

If this gives you warnings about non-monotonic DTS errors, try removing `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` and / or `-reset_timestamps`.